# What's the word for someone who is prepared in advance

Tags: single-word-requests

What will you call someone who is prepared in advance for all the events/things?

I want a word which i can use in context where it's good to be prepared in advance.

Ex. If a person is well prepared for any event/meeting then it's a good thing. I want to use it as a adjective.

Comment: Former Boy Scout?

Comment: Nananananana Batman!

Comment: Are they prepared on purpose or incidentally? If it's on purpose, what is the reason? Is the preparedness a good thing, a morbid obsession, their hobby, their job? What part of speech are you looking for? What is the context? What dialect? What register?

Comment: Can you be prepared after the fact?

Comment: @RegDwigнt : see I updated question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying a point. It would help if you clarified the other points as well.

Comment: @RegDwigнt : why is it still on hold?

Comment: See my previous comment. And my comment before that. Clarifying just one point out of many is not enough. For starters, the answers suggest both nouns and adjectives.

Comment: @RegDwigнt : I haven't been using this much. So sorry for it. Updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ever-ready](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever-ready) is an adjective meaning *permanently accessible, available, or prepared*.

It is probably more widely recognised as the trademark [*Eveready*](http://www.eveready.com/Pages/default.aspx), associated with the international flashlight and battery manufacturer. Colloquially, one might refer to someone who is always prepared as Mr Eveready.

Answer (score 2):

These are some words that can be used to convey preparedness. But I don't know of any particular word for a person like that.

```
ready, equipped, set, primed
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single, specific word for this; you'd have to use "He likes to be prepared" or something similar.

There is the non-standard *[prepper](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=prepper)*, but this is intrinsically linked to survivalism, and as such might not convey the (general) sense you are looking for, perhaps.

Comment: No I don't need a word for survivalism. thanks for trying.

Comment: Well, it *does* refer to people who like being prepared ...